# Como asignar una HotKey con JQuery a un boton

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Este es el código de mi botón en **HTML** con **CSS** quisiera que por medio de **JS** asignarle en ves de darle clic por ejemplo un F7 o F8 o cualquier combinacion de teclas con **jQuery**.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-flat">Guardar</button>
</div>
```

Comment: El boton esta dentro de un `<form>`?

Comment: ¿Qué has investigado sobre el tema? Hay varias preguntas que tratan sobre esto en el sitio (cómo detectar teclas pulsadas y cómo lanzar un evento de un elemento).

Comment: Si esta dentro de un form afecta en algo ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sumando a la respuesta anterior.
Te dejo un ejemplo basico, con la combinacion de teclas "ctrl + a"

**HTML**

```
  <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" id="btn_principal" class="btn btn-success btn-flat">Guardar</button>
 </div>
```

**JS**

```
 document.addEventListener('keyup', event => {
     // combinación de teclas ctrl + a
      if (event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode === 65) {
           document.getElementById("btn_principal").click();
      }
    }, false)
```

Podes buscar los códigos de teclas en http://keycode.info/

Ademas te recomiendo que investigues sobre los eventos de teclado, ya que hay varios.

- **onkeydown**: Corresponde al hecho de pulsar una tecla y no soltarla.
- **onkeypress**: Corresponde a la propia pulsación de la tecla.
- **onkeyup**: Corresponde al hecho de soltar una tecla que estaba pulsada.

Fuente: https://aprende-web.net/javascript/js6_4.php

Answer (score 2):

Para lograr lo que quieres deberias darle un id al boton.  Luego si no quieres que el click funcione puedes desabilitarlo.  Finalmente, es simplemente cuestion de usar el codigo de la tecla que deseas.  Algo asi:

```js
$(document).on('keydown', function(event) {  
  if(event.which == 118) { // F7
    $("#Guardar").click();
  }
});
$("#Guardar").on('click', function() {
  alert('hello');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
       <button id="Guardar" type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-flat" disabled>Guardar</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Todo bien me funcione excelente, pero ahora bien tengo una duda en chrome me sale esto: [Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'mousewheel' event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5745543795965952

Comment: Eso es solo una recomendacion que viene de algun handler de `mousewheel`.  No tiene nada que ver con el codigo de la respuesta.

Comment: [`which` se considera obsoleto](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/which), se ha quitado del estándar web y no debería usarse porque podría dejar de funcionar. En su lugar debería utilizarse [`key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key).

Comment: Oh ya voy a cambiar ese parametro entonces gracias Alvaro

Comment: event.keyCode == 118

Comment: Asi deberia quedar cierto?